# How to convert array or string to array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

in my javascript program I have a function (not in my reach to edit) that returns a string or an array.

So I either have the output `"one"` or `["one", "two"]`

I would like the output to alway be an array, so if it returns one string `"one"` I would like to have it as `["one"]`.

What is the most easy way to do this? (Preferably without an if)

I tried:

```
var arr = aFunction().split();
```

But when it does return an array, this won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As @Jaromanda X pointed out in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33972591/847818) you can use concat:

```
var result = [].concat(aFunction());
```

kudos!

---

I don't think there is a way to do this without an if, so just check if the output is a String and, in case, add it to an empty array.

```
var result = myFn();
if (typeof result === 'string' || result instanceof String) {
    result = new Array(result);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use array [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function

```
var arr = [].concat(aFunction());
```

Answer (score -1):

Without "**if**" ;) (but internally the ternary operator is doing the if / else stuff)

```
var result = aFunction();
result = (typeof result == "string") ? [result] : result;
```